# What does this factory prototype code do?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, oop, design-patterns, prototype

What does this code do? I mean specifically with the prototype part. The chain object when it is passed in is an object of CSS name / value pairs. I think that the defaultFactory returns an object with name value pairs. What I don't know is what setting the prototype does.

```
 function addDefaultStyleToProtoChain(chain):Object {
    // If there's a defaultFactory for this style sheet,
    // then add the object it produces to the chain.
    if (defaultFactory != null)
    {
        var originalChain:Object = chain;

        // from here on...
        defaultFactory.prototype = chain;
        chain = new defaultFactory();
        defaultFactory.prototype = null;
     }

     return chain;
  }
```

This is in the addDefaultStyleToProtoChain method of the CSSStyleDeclaration class of the Flex 4.6 SDK

For context, what if:

```
   var o:Object = new defaultFactory();
   trace(o) // {fontFamily:Arial, color:blue};
   trace(chain) // {color:red, fontWeight:bold}

   defaultFactory.prototype = chain;
   chain = new defaultFactory(); 
   trace(chain) // ???
```

What does chain equal?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UPDATE
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Based on the answer below this is what is going on:

```
// create a function that returns an object
var myDynamicDefinition:Function = function() {
    this.name = "initialvalue";
    trace('this.name='+this.name); // returns this.name=initialvalue
}

var dynamicDefinitionInstance = new myDynamicDefinition(); // create an instance of myDynamicDefinition
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(dynamicDefinitionInstance));// returns name = "initialvalue"

// create a new definition and assign it to our dynamic definitions
var newDefinition = {color:"red", name:"newObjectValue"};
myDynamicDefinition.prototype = newDefinition;

// create a new instance with new definition
var dynamicDefinitionInstance2 = new myDynamicDefinition();  // create an instance of myDynamicDefinition
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(dynamicDefinitionInstance2)); // returns name = "initialvalue" color = "red"

// delete name property instance
delete dynamicDefinitionInstance2.name;
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(dynamicDefinitionInstance2)); // returns name = "newObjectValue" color = "red"

// set prototype to null 
myDynamicDefinition.prototype = null;

// create a new instance 
var dynamicDefinitionInstance3 = new myDynamicDefinition(); 
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(dynamicDefinitionInstance2)); // returns name = "newObjectValue" color = "red"
```

It looks like when the prototype object is set to an object that contains a property of the same name the property value on new instances does NOT change after a new instance is created. So it makes no difference at first. If that property is deleted then the value on the prototype object is used as a FALLBACK. See the example code above and the return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had looked at SDK and found that `defaultFactory` is function like

```
newStyleDeclaration.defaultFactory = function():void
{
    leftMargin = 50;
    rightMargin = 50;
}
```

So, when you apply this function as constructor to an object (via prototype), you simply create a new object, that has merged properties from the first object with changes, declared in the function.

```
    var def : Function = function() {
        this.someDefChanges = "someDefChanges";
    }

    var o1 = {testValueO2 : "testValueO2"};
    def.prototype = o1;
    var o2 = new def();
    def.prototype = null;

    // o1 = {testValueO2: "testValueO2"}
    // o2 = {someDefChanges: "someDefChanges", testValueO2: "testValueO2"}
```

Hope, I got your question right

Answer (score 1):

Setting the prototype basically modifies a class, so that from that point forward any object you instantiate of that class gets the new version of the class instead of the original.

So lets say my language has a native class of foo. If I want to add a method to foo, not just create a class that extends foo, but actually add the method to foo. I would modify foo's prototype. So after that code is executed, all instances of foo have my new method.

Usually you don't want to do this, it's equivalent to monkey patching, but if you are writing a framework or SDK, and it's well documented, you're probably in the clear.

Comment: So it adds in the properties and methods to the existing class or replaces the existing class? If it merges in new properties what if the method already exists? Is it over written?

Comment: I would think of it as replacing the existing class, though not really. It replaces what defines the existing class, and what that means to objects that implement that class. Yes, you can override existing methods. I believe the term is "overload" the method.